# Sqoop is loading 'image'-BLOB data from source with 'spacing' in hive table

Tags: hive, sqoop, blobstorage

i had ran the manual SQOOP script to ingest the 'image'-BLOB data from the SQL Server source(test DB) to Hive table. The source data appears like HEXA(example: 1000000000000000AAU8XXXYXXX1XAXX00) value ,but the data that got ingested in hive appear with 'Spacing' between every 2 characters (example: 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA U8 XX XY XX X1 XA XX 00) . Any suggestion to fix this issue!

I am using : --map-column-hive image=String

Comment: you are reading BLOB binary data as string - so i dont think this is going to be imported correctly

Comment: Convert BLOB to STRING explicitly in the QUERY using some functions (if it is possible at all ) or use BINARY

Comment: --map-column-hive image=binary  , as well but it doesn't resolve the issue